# Replicate brush browser icon view interface

Tags: shaders, interface

I've been looking for a way to replicate this browser:

[image]

I have tried this code, but seems that I missing something:

```
import bpy

class BrushIconsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Brush Icons"
    bl_idname = "PT_BrushIcons"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "texture_paint"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Get the active brush
        brush = bpy.context.tool_settings.image_paint.brush

        # Display the brush icon
        layout.label(text="Active Brush:")
        layout.template_icon_view(brush, "icon", scale=8.0)

        # Display a list of available brushes with icons
        layout.label(text="Available Brushes:")
        row = layout.row()
        for brush in bpy.data.brushes:
            row.template_icon_view(brush, "icon", scale=1.0)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(BrushIconsPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BrushIconsPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution if it could help anyone:

```
brush = bpy.context.tool_settings.image_paint

row.column().template_ID_preview(brush, "brush", new="brush.add", rows=3, cols=8, hide_buttons=False)
```